# automapper mapping not working between viewmodel and entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, automapper

I have created the map between source and destination as shown in below

```
Mapper.CreateMap <SampleMVC.Models.ViewModel, SampleMVC.CustomerMaster> ()
```

The name of attributes between source and destination are exactly same, but at the time of storing the record in database it save as NULL values.

I slightly altered the code and introduce the forMember as shown in below

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<SampleMVC.Models.ViewModel, SampleMVC.CustomerMaster>()
                   .ForMember(dest => dest.FatherName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Customerss.FatherName))
                   .ForMember(dest => dest.CustomerName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Customerss.CustomerName));
```

and it started working.

Can any one tell , why direct mapping is not working and what needs to be done?

**ViewModel**

```
namespace SampleMVC.Models
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public EducationMaster Education { get; set; }
        public Customers Customerss { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Customer Model**

```
public class Customers
    {
        [Key]
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide Customer Name", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide Father Name", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string FatherName { get; set; }
        public string MotherName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide DOB", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        public string DOB { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression(@"^([0-9a-zA-Z]([\+\-_\.][0-9a-zA-Z]+)*)+@(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]*\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})$", ErrorMessage = "Your email address is not in a valid format. Example of correct format: joe.example@example.org")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid Phone number")]
        public string MobileNo { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid Phone number")]
        public string OfficeNo { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid Phone number")]
        public string ResidenceNo { get; set; }


    }
```

**Education Model**

```
namespace SampleMVC.Models
{
    public class EducationMaster
    {
        [Key]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select Education", AllowEmptyStrings = false), Range(1, Int32.MaxValue)]
        public int EducationMasterId { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide both the `ViewModel` and the `CustomerMaster` class definitions in your question.

Comment: Your source properties are on a nested object (`src.Customerss.FatherName`) whereas your destination properties are not (`dest.FatherName`).

Comment: @James What I need to do for nesting the properties?

Comment: Hi @PatrickSteele  Updated the ViewModel , whereas  CustomerMaster is the entity/table

Comment: @ParagPathari are you mapping properties on the source object or are they all coming from the `src.Customerss` child object?

Comment: Without seeing the `CustomerMaster` class, it's difficult to answer your question.

Comment: @James all the attributes are coming from the viewmodel. I have created viewmodel on the top which consist of attributes of customer and education class